# Query bindings with Wpf

Tags: c#, database

im new to database and programming at all, but i have a problem.
I want to open a xml file and load it into my database.
My program use the openfileDialog and i do it through a binding.

```
private string _pathselected;
public string pathselected 
{
    get 
    {
        return _pathselected;
    }
    set 
    {
        pathselected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("pathselected");
    }
}
```

this is the string i bind to using the openFileDialog

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog.Filter = "xml files(*.xml) | *.xml | All files(*.*) | *.* ";

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    pathselected = openFileDialog.FileName;

}
```

Everything works and i used it multiple times to acces it in xaml for a datagrid or whatsoever.
In theory i want to use the pathselected binding  in query. do i have to bind it again or what, im out of clues and dont know what i have to sarch for. And im sure i cant just use the already existing bindig without binding it to query first.

right now my query looks like this

```
select cast(c as xml) from
openrowset(bulk 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.xml' , single_blob) as T(c)
```

and i want the path to be my pathselected property but as i said i dont know how to do it

Comment: Could you provide some code which shows more of the "query" part you mentioned

Comment: Could you explain how you plan on using the `pathselected` property in a query? Some piece of code will really help.

Comment: i added it how i use it right now which is not dynamic